# Somar valores de uma tabela quando o cliente for o mesmo

Tags: php, laravel

Observem a tabela abaixo, o resultado final deve ser este: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como faço para que somente o **ultimo registro** do cliente na tabela exiba o valor total de cheques.

Estou utilizando PHP (Laravel 5.4) e preciso gerar um relatório neste formato, porém não tenho ideia de como fazer isto.

**EDITADO**

Este é o array que recebo para realizar o tratamento daquela forma da imagem acima. Neste caso, somente o **CLIENTE 6** tem mais do que 1 lançamento, eu preciso imprimir todos na tabela porém somente na ultima linha devo mostrar o total de todos os registros do **CLIENTE 6**.

```
array:8 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "VENCIMENTOCH" => "2017-11-06"
    "VALORCHEQUE" => "307.8900"
    "NOME" => "CLIENTE 1"
    "CPFCNPJ" => "00000000001"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "VENCIMENTOCH" => "2017-11-06"
    "VALORCHEQUE" => "272.8100"
    "NOME" => "CLIENTE 2"
    "CPFCNPJ" => "00000000002"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    "VENCIMENTOCH" => "2017-11-07"
    "VALORCHEQUE" => "696.0000"
    "NOME" => "CLIENTE 3"
    "CPFCNPJ" => "00000000003"
  ]
  3 => array:4 [▼
    "VENCIMENTOCH" => "2017-11-06"
    "VALORCHEQUE" => "312.0000"
    "NOME" => "CLIENTE 4"
    "CPFCNPJ" => "00000000004"
  ]
  4 => array:4 [▼
    "VENCIMENTOCH" => "2017-11-10"
    "VALORCHEQUE" => "320.0000"
    "NOME" => "CLIENTE 5"
    "CPFCNPJ" => "00000000005"
  ]
  5 => array:4 [▼
    "VENCIMENTOCH" => "2017-11-18"
    "VALORCHEQUE" => "383.8200"
    "NOME" => "CLIENTE 6"
    "CPFCNPJ" => "00000000006"
  ]
  6 => array:4 [▼
    "VENCIMENTOCH" => "2017-11-13"
    "VALORCHEQUE" => "323.4000"
    "NOME" => "CLIENTE 6"
    "CPFCNPJ" => "00000000006"
  ]
  7 => array:4 [▼
    "VENCIMENTOCH" => "2017-11-04"
    "VALORCHEQUE" => "320.8600"
    "NOME" => "CLIENTE 6"
    "CPFCNPJ" => "00000000006"
  ]
]
```

Com o array acima eu tenho que gerar este resultado final:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Isto é pseudo código:

```
     $array = [];

        $account =  Client::with('users')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

       $length = count($posts);

            $user = new Controller();

       for($i = 0; $i < = $length ; $i++){ 
             $array[$i]['total'] =$account[$i]->$user->getMaxSimpleUser($account[$i]->user->User_id);


function getMaxSimpleUser(){

$max = 0;
       $account =  Client::where('user_id', '=', $id)->get();
       foreach($accounts as $account){  $max += $max + $account->total;} return $max }
```

Comment: Pra mim não funciona este código. Observe que a tabela não tem só um cliente, preciso fazer isto na mesma tabela, não separadamente.

Comment: Vou editar a resposta @DavidSantos

Comment: @DavidSantos Vê agora! :)

Comment: Não, acho que não estamos nos entendendo. Editei a pergunta colocando mais especificadamente o que eu preciso buscar.